# Would you prefer Aptana or Dreamweaver for front end development?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, aptana, frontend

I have access to a copy of Dreamweaver CS5 which is paid for, so I am trying to decide if I would rather use Dreamweaver or Aptana. They seem fairly similar in basic function, but I'm sure their complete list of features differs a lot. The only thing I care about at the bottom line is which one is going to allow me to code HTML, CSS and JS fastest from start to finish.

I am familiar with both programs, (so there is no need to point me to a page describing the features of either one) but I am not a long-time power-user of either. I'm asking for opinions from those more experienced than myself.

Thoughts from those who have used both for front end development?

Answer (score 2):

I used to prefer Dreamweaver for html and CSS work. It is easyer to work in split mode (see code, and design window at the same time)

I used Aptana for JS development as it seems faster as a code editor.

Now days I normally do more HTML/CSS in any text exitor and or directly in the browser using firefox firebug or Chrome to edit the styles and see how they will look exactly in the browser.

When I do JavaScript or a lot of HTML and CSS by hand then I use [Web Storm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) as it has really nice interface, keyboard short cuts, code completion, refactoring etc that RAPIDLY insreases my speed.

Answer (score 1):

My preference depends entirely on whether I am developing HTML/CSS or if I'm developing JavaScript / server-side languages.

For basic HTML/CSS I use Firebug because of its amazing versatility and ability to get immediate visual output in the browser.

However, when I'm developing in programming languages or working on multiple pages at once, I use an IDE (I'm trying a bunch out right now, my favorite being Web Storm which I learned about a week or so ago). Since you are familiar with Aptana already, I would say stay with it as it has a lot going for, especially over Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

I tend not to use a full blown IDE as I find them rather bloated.

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) is my weapon of choice, a brilliant, lightweight code editor with a host of features and best of all - it's free.